# Angular 2 - Structural Directive - How to insert a router link

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

How do I add a routerLink attribute programmaticaly ? inside a directive

```
@Input() set siteMapLeaf(caption:string)
{
    let view = this.templateRef.createEmbeddedView({});
    const parentNode = view.rootNodes[0];

    // <a routerLink="dashBoard">Some Text</a>
    const leaf = this.renderer.createElement('a');
    const text = this.renderer.createText(caption);
    this.renderer.appendChild(leaf, text);
    this.renderer.addClass(leaf,'siteMapLeafDiv');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(leaf,'routerLink','dashBoard');

    this.renderer.insertBefore(parentNode,leaf, parentNode.firstChild);
    this.viewContainer.insert(view);
}
```

is it possible ?
or do I have to inject a component that deals with the routerLink ?

thanks

Comment: Use `ng-template`. You can't add directive dynamically

Comment: do you have an example ? I dont see how.thanks

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-etlype?file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from yurzui

one can't add directive dynamically

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<div *siteMapLeaf="'Campaign' as item">
  <a class="siteMapLeafDiv" [routerLink]="item.link">{{item.text}}</a>
</div>
```